# Abstract methods visibility in PHP Object-oriented programming

Tags: php, access-modifiers

I have an abstract class and I don't know the difference between the two ways of defining the `test()` function

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract protected function test();
}
```

and this

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract function test();
}
```

Does it make any difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php):

> Class methods may be defined as public, private, or protected. **Methods declared without any explicit visibility keyword are defined as public.**

So the answer is no, they are not the same:

- `abstract protected function test();` will be accessible only within the class itself and by inheriting and parent classes;
- `abstract function test();` can be accessed from everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

For compatibility with PHP 4 (where everything is public and there is no way to specify something else), the [default visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php#language.oop5.visiblity-methods) of class properties and methods is `public`.

Because of this,

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract function test();
}
```

is the same as:

```
abstract class Foo {
    abstract public function test();
}
```